# Does CreatePerOwinContext properly dispose instance at end of Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to better understand what is happening with the default behavior of registering types with CreatePerOwinContext. For reference I am using a default MVC 4.5.2 application with individual user accounts template from microsoft.

<del>If you put a breakpoint at the ApplicationDbContext Create method (or any of the CreatePerOwinContext instances), you will see it is called once at the beginning of the request, as expected, then the page is rendered and request ends. After the request ends, the Create method is called again. Why is this happening?

I tracked application_endrequest on global asax to verify that the 2nd Create call is occuring after the request ends.</del>

On a possibly related note, **How can I ensure the instances are properly disposed?**

Edit: This turned out to be BrowserLink initiating a request while debugging. When turning off BrowserLink, there is only one request as expected. Still a question on ensuring the instance introduced is disposed. Title edited for clarification.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same request? I've seen when requests for JS or CSS also going through the same pipeline.

Comment: Actually after some more debugging, turns out this was BrowserLink ... thanks for the lead